# Finding the square sum of an array with pthreads in C

Tags: c, pthreads

What I need to do is calculate the square sum of an array. The array and the number of threads must be given by the user, and we assume the number of elements and the number of threads are integrally divided.

My code doesn't even compile.. I know I have issues with the pointers, and I should place mutexes but I don't know where exactly. Can you point me to the right direction? I will appreciate it a lot.

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int part = 0;
int local_elements = 0;

void* square_sum(void* arg)
{
    int local_sum = 0;
    int *element_array[] = (int *)arg;

    //Each thread computes its part
    int thread_part = part++;

    for (int i = thread_part * loc_elements; i < (thread_part + 1)*loc_elements; i++) {
        local_sum += element_array[i] * element_array[i];
    }

    return (void*)&local_sum;
}

main()
{
    int threads, total_elements;
    int i;
    int total_sum = 0;

    printf("Give the number of threads: ");
    scanf("%d", &threads);

    printf("Give the number of the elements you want: ");
    scanf("%d", &total_elements;)
        int element_array[total_elements];

    //How many elements each thread gets
    local_elements = total_elements / threads;

    printf("Give the %d elements \n", total_elements);
    for (i = 0; i < total_elements; i++) {
        printf("No. %d:", i);
        scanf("%d", &element_array[i]);
    }

    pthread_t newthread[threads];
    //Creating the threads
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        //The start routine gets the whole element_array
        pthread_create(&newthread[i], NULL, square_sum, &element_array);
    }

    int loc_sum;
    //Waiting for each thread to finish and creating the total_sum
    for (int i = 0; i < threads; i++) {
        pthread_join(newthread[i], &loc_sum);
        total_sum += loc_sum;
    }

    printf("The total sum is: %d", &total_sum);
}
```

Comment: **square sum** *of an array* [...] *we assume the number of elements and the number of threads are* **integrally divided** – would you please give an explanation (or links to those) for mathematically illiterate?

Comment: "My code doesn't even compile" A couple of the compilation errors are straightforward, you should be able to fix those. Look at the others and ask a specific question about which errors you don't understand.

Comment: `int *element_array[] = (int *)arg;` is wrong — you probably mean `int *element_array = (int *)arg;` (though the cast is superfluous); you might mean `int (*element_array)[SIZE] = arg;` for some size of the array, and you'd then use `element_array[a][b]` to access elements of the array (which is why you probably don't intend to use this notation — pointers to arrays are somewhat esoteric).

Comment: You have `//Each thread computes its part` — `int thread_part = part++;` — which has the threads access a shared variable without proper access control (a mutex would be sensible).  You might or might not get away without using one.  You'd do better to pass the part number to the thread as part of a structure telling it what to do (the structure being passed by pointer to the thread function).

Comment: You have a global variable `local_elements`, but your thread function code refers to `loc_elements`.  In general, global variables are anathema in threaded code — avoid them like the plague they are.  Global constants are less of a problem, and `local_elements` is constant once the threads are started.  But you should be able to fix 'undefined variable' problems in your code without coming to SO.

Comment: you are return a pointer that points to the stack variable "local_sum" which will probably be garbage after you return from the function.  Either make it global, make it static to the function, or put it on the heap with malloc.